# Eclipse-Papyrus create node at droplocation

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, location, papyrus

I want to drag and drop some items out of a list into the model viewer.
I already can do so but the node is always created at the top left of the viewer and i don't know how to create the node at the dropped location.

Here is the function that creates the node (x and y are the coordinates of  the droplocation)

```
private View addNode(Node node, View deploymentView) {

    // use the view service to create the types. This is a bit cleaner than
    // using the sequence-diagram view provider directlys
    final String nodeType = UMLVisualIDRegistry
            .getType(org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.deployment.edit.parts.NodeEditPart.VISUAL_ID);
    org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation.Node nodeView = ViewService.createNode(deploymentView.getDiagram(), node,
            nodeType, UMLDiagramEditorPlugin.DIAGRAM_PREFERENCES_HINT);
    Bounds location = NotationFactory.eINSTANCE.createBounds();

    System.out.println("Dropped at x: "+ (int)this.x + " y: "+ (int)this.y);
    location.setX((int)this.x);
    location.setY((int)this.y);
    return nodeView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay wasn't that hard to fix it ...

```
private View addNode(Node node, View deploymentView) {


    // use the view service to create the types. This is a bit cleaner than
    // using the sequence-diagram view provider directlys
    final String nodeType = UMLVisualIDRegistry
            .getType(org.eclipse.papyrus.uml.diagram.deployment.edit.parts.NodeEditPart.VISUAL_ID);
    org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation.Node nodeView = ViewService.createNode(deploymentView.getDiagram(), node,
            nodeType, UMLDiagramEditorPlugin.DIAGRAM_PREFERENCES_HINT);


    System.out.println("Dropped at x: "+ (int)this.x + " y: "+ (int)this.y);

    //for(int i=0;i<nodeView.getDiagram().getChildren().size();i++)System.out.println(nodeView.getDiagram().getChildren().get(i).toString());

    nodeView.setLayoutConstraint(NotationFactory.eINSTANCE
            .createLocation());
    Location location = (Location) nodeView.getLayoutConstraint();
    location.setX((int)this.x);
    location.setY((int)this.y);
    return nodeView;
}
```